# How remove null column while merge two dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

While i merge tow dataset ds1 and ds2 null column add after i merge code as below

ds1.Merge(ds2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);

ds1.AcceptChanges();

this both method is not working.

```
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter SqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblProductInventory", myConn);
        SqlDA.Fill(ds1, "MyTable");

        SqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblProductCategories", myConn);
        SqlDA.Fill(ds2, "MyTable");

        //ds1.Merge(ds2);
        ds1.Merge(ds2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
        ds1.AcceptChanges();


        GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As there is no relationship between the two datasets, need to add two columns to ds1 like below:

```
ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("CategoryId", typeof(string));
ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(string));
```

then you can do this:

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; temp++)
{
    ds1.Tables[0].Rows[temp]["CategoryId"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[temp]["CategoryId"];
    ds1.Tables[0].Rows[temp]["CategoryName"] = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[temp]["CategoryName"];
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply but addwithkey option also not working still null colum showing as per above screenshot

Comment: How I can achieve using merge?